# Using Angular for a game (60 fps)

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm building a 2D game.  I have a physics system running in the background that handles moving bodies around.  Each of these bodies corresponds to an absolutely positioned sprite div.  I need to set the position of each sprite to the position of the corresponding body at least 30 times per second to get smooth animation.

If I were to use Angular for this project, how would I go about setting the sprite positions?  Do I just bind the position with ng-style and call $scope.$apply at 60 fps from requestAnimationFrame?  There is a bunch of other gui stuff on my page so I could see this being pretty slow.  Should I just not use angular for this?

Comment: I previously did a project that combined angular and webgl/canvas. Basically, I targeted a canvas element with a directive that would handle the drawing.

Comment: I suppose you could use angular for this but its not really what it was designed for.  Have you considered phaser.io?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you gave the option for this answer in your question, I wouldn't recommend angular for this project.  If you want to use a library, I'd suggest looking into [PhaserJS](http://phaser.io)

Comment: I actually looked into Phaser.  But I've found that canvas based game engines use a lot of CPU -- whereas pure CSS is more lightweight.  I think Phaser is overkill for this project.

Comment: Phaser uses webgl where available and falls back to canvas as required. If you don't need phaser I'd suggest plain js or jquery. Angular is designed for spas and not really games as much.